# Is this endgame scenario winnable for white?

Tags: analysis, endgame

```
[title "White to move"]
[fen "8/8/4kr1Q/1p2pp2/1P1n4/p3K3/P7/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

I’m looking at this current position, and I think I'm going to lose, as I have limited mobility with both my king and queen. But a friend suggested otherwise, saying that I should put more focus on destabilizing the pawns up front, and therefore I have a high probability of winning otherwise.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a game you are playing currently? Do the rules allow you to get help from anyone in the world?

Comment: This is against a bot on a high difficulty(for me), so I don't think it breaks any rules.

Comment: I only see a perpetual for White here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks rather lost (for white) to me.  Black basically has a fortress except for the a3 pawn.

If white wanted to win this (with black not doing anything), you'd have to win the a3 pawn, play a4 and promote a pawn. I don't think white has time for this as black's e,f-pawns will run very fast.

So the only realistic chance is a perpetual.

Answer (score 1):

Black threatens Nc2+ and this allows one or both the white pawns to be captured. You would have to virtually dedicate your Q to preventing this. No matter what you attempt, Black has strong replies.

I agree perpetual check is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

Is it winnable?  Maybe.  Against a person that could happen.  Against a good engine more unclear.

The final result is past the horizon that people and likely machine can compute.

I see white getting at least a draw.  And I can see that white might win.  I would not resign nor accept a draw with white.  Not against a human.  I would keep playing and trying to win.  Keeping the possibility of perpetual in reserve.

I would first look at what seems to be the possibilities that would arise.  It will depend a lot on how black chooses to play. I can see black ensuring the draw if he does not try to win. But it is still hard to tell what will happen with certainty.